# How to wait for child without using wait in C++

Tags: c++

I tried to do it in g++ and my code is shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void h(int sNo){
    cout << "Called!" << endl;
}

int main(){
    signal(SIGINT,h);
    pid_t id;
    switch(id = fork()){
    case 0:
        kill(getppid(),0);
        exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        while(kill(id,0)==0){
            cout << "waiting for child" << endl; sleep(1);
        }
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But failed! as parent process is not stopping to wait....!

Comment: Maybe because the child already exited? Do you know whether child process is still running?

Comment: kill(id,0)==0 condition checks whether the child exists or not. If exists this condition becomes true otherwise not.

Comment: Why can you not use `wait()` or `waitpid()`? It is the intended way of achieving what you need and also of not leaving zombies.

Comment: Yeah, but I was thinking of an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child process is dead, but since you didn't call `wait` it became a "zombie".  `kill` will always return `0` because the child is still living... as an undead :P

Check out the notes section: http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait

Excerpt:

> A child that terminates, but has not been waited for becomes a
>   "zombie". The kernel maintains a minimal set of information about the
>   zombie process (PID, termination status, resource usage information)
>   in order to allow the parent to later perform a wait to obtain
>   information about the child. As long as a zombie is not removed from
>   the system via a wait, it will consume a slot in the kernel process
>   table, and if this table fills, it will not be possible to create
>   further processes. If a parent process terminates, then its "zombie"
>   children (if any) are adopted by init(8), which automatically performs
>   a wait to remove the zombies.

**Update:** Just read that you didn't want to use `wait`, but I am not sure why you wouldn't want to do that.  Using `wait` is the right way to ensure resources used by the child is cleaned up.

Comment: I was thinking of an alternative.

The best answer. Thanks!